# Euler type sums involving harmonic numer and hyperbolic sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to calculate the closed form of the following Euler type Sums
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}}}{{{n^p}\sinh \left( {n\pi } \right)}}}  = ?$$
Here the harmonic number $H_n$ is defined by
$${H_n} = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{1}{j}}$$.

Comment: What makes you thinking that a closed form exists ?

Comment: Since $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}}}{{{n^k}}}}$  have a closed form that $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{H_n}}}{{{n^k}}}}  = \frac{1}{2}\left\{ {\left( {k + 2} \right)\zeta \left( {k + 1} \right) - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{k - 2} {\zeta \left( {k - i} \right)\zeta \left( {i + 1} \right)} } \right\}.$$ Hence, I think the sums above that it shoud be a similar closed form.

Comment: Mi first temptation is to expand $\frac{1}{\sinh(\pi n)}$ as $$\frac{1}{\pi n}+\sum_{m\geq 1}(-1)^m\left(\frac{1}{n-mi}+\frac{1}{n+mi}\right)$$ then hope that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n^p(n+mi)}$$ is manageable in terms of Hurwitz zeta functions, as a natural extension of the $m=0$ case.